# ThreeJS: Map circular center of a square image to truncated sphere?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to build a viewer for images shot with a Pixpro SP360.  This camera has a fisheye lens with a 214-degree field of view.   The resulting image is a black square with a circular image centered in it.  The diameter of the circle (and the side of the square) is 1440px.

I want to use these images as textures on a truncated sphere (phiLength of (Math.PI * 2) and thetaLength of ((214/360) * Math.PI).   The problem is that the texture mapping seems to include the black areas that are more than 1440px from the center.  I've tried playing with various values of texture.mapping, texture.wrapS & texture.wrapT without success.

The code I'm using is adapted from, and almost identical to, http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular with the exception of the truncation of the sphere.

Is there a way map just the circular center part of the image to the truncated sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a photo editor and change the black area to be transparent.

Or you could write your own fragment shader to only use the center circular bit of the texture map. Something like this:

```
<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

    varying vec2 vUv;  
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main() {
        vec4 zerovec = vec4(0.,0.,1.,1.);
        vec2 uv = vUv;
        vec4 tex1 = texture2D( iChannel0,  uv);
        float radius = sqrt(pow(uv.x - .5,2.) + pow(uv.y-.5,2.));
        if (radius < 0.45)
            gl_FragColor = tex1;
        else
            gl_FragColor = zerovec;
    }

</script>
```

There are still some mapping artifacts in my example, but it gets rid of the bounding square.
Complete example here: http://rwoodley.org/MyContent/WIP/33-StackOverflowShaderExample/06.html

Comment: Thanks Bob, but that doesn't actually solve the problem.  Event if the black areas outside the image circle are transparent, Three.js appears to clamp the edges of the image to the edge of the truncated sphere, regardless of the alpha.

I've tried changing texture.wrapS (and .wrapT) from THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping to THREE.RepeatWrapping and texture.repeat.set = (1,1) but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I guess you need to write a fragment shader and do the UV mapping yourself.

Comment: Many Thanks Bob!   I'll study that and give it a try.  I'll report back.

Comment: @RichardMilewski Hi, do you have any progress on this?

Comment: I haven't had much time to work on this lately, but....
The WebVR team at Mozilla has released a javascript framework for doing VR on the web. (https://aframe.io).  I did file an issue in their GitHub repo about this problem (#869).  A-Frame is under intense development right now, so I have hopes someone will deal with it soon.

There's a tracking issue (#880) for custom shader support, check that out also for signs of progress.